# python sintax problem for solidity compilator

Tags: python, solidity, traceback, web3py, brownie

I have problem connected to python. I want to compile solidity files using python. But getting error.

```
    import json


from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc



with open("./SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()



# Solidity source code
compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {
                    "*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.bytecode.sourceMap"]
                }
            }
        },
    },
    solc_version="0.9.0",
)

with open("compiled_code.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(compiled_sol, file)
```

**first python where I get error and second solidity its' fine  **

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTq9C.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuyy2.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include errors as text and not images.

Comment: As the error states,  ```solc 0.9.0 has not been installed, Use solcx.install('0.9.0') to install```.  Your second set of code doesn't use solc 0.9.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't `0.9.0` solc version yet. Check official [releases](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases) list and use available one. If you want to use the latest one, modify you code into:

```py
solc_version="0.8.13",
```